# test a recordset for values to exclude

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Hmmm...crappy question, but I didn't know how to phrase this:

I have a sweet jquery drag and drop page where someone can drop category names from a list of all categories onto an item.  This is then saved in a db lookup table with itemID and categoryID.

So far so good.

When it comes to editing the item I can populate the list of categories already applied easily.

Now I want to populate the list of categories leaving out those that are already applied to the item.  This is where I am stuck.

e.g. if the list of 26 categories matches each letter of the alphabet (to make this easy) and the item already has categories B D and E applied, how can I then just display categories A, C, F, H, I etc leaving out the applied ones.

I don't want to have to lpop through the applied category array for each category item in the list - seems like a waste of resources.

Is there some way to use and array_search type function?

I hope this makes sense without being over complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do it in the SQL?:

```
SELECT category_id FROM categories WHERE category_id NOT IN (SELECT category_id FROM items WHERE item_id = x);
```

Comment: Ahhh...so easy when someone points out the obvious.  Thanks AJweb.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get it.

```
$item_cats = array('B','D','E');
$cats = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G');
print_r(array_diff($cats, $item_cats));
```

Is this helps?